# Need to delete string from arraylist which contains letters in it and don't touch if contains other

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm trying to make a method fix to remove all words which contain letter *r* in it,then multiply x2 all words which contain letter *l* in it and if word contains *r* and *l* in it don't touch it. Method works but not how it must. I think it have to do something with remove.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("rose"); //0
        list.add("liar"); //1
        list.add("lisa"); //2
        list = fix(list);

        for (String s : list)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fix(ArrayList<String> list) {
        //
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            String s = list.get(i);

            boolean strL = s.contains("l");
            boolean strR = s.contains("r");

            if(strR){
                temp.remove(s);
            }
            if(strL && strR) {
                temp.add(s);
            } else {

                if(strL) {
                    temp.add(s);
                    temp.add(s);
                         }
            }

        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Iterator,
and the exclusive or (^) operator.

```
public static ArrayList<String> fix(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator<String> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String str = i.next();
        boolean isL = str.contains("l");
        boolean isR = str.contains("r");

        if (isR ^ isL) {
            if (isR) {
                i.remove();
            }
            else {
                temp.add(str);
                temp.add(str);
            }
        }
        else {
            temp.add(str);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic should be:

```
if (strL != strR) {
    list.remove(word);
}
```

If it contains neither, it does nothing.  If it contains both, it does nothing.  If it contains L and not R, it removes it.  If it contains R and not L, it removes it.

Of course my code is modifying the input list.  If you want to build up a `temp` list instead, it should be easy to extrapolate my answer to get what you want.

Comment: im sorry, i explained bad =| what it have to do, it have to multiply all words by 2 which contain letter (l) in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    if(strL && strR) {
        temp.add(s);
    } else if(strL) {
        // do nothing
    } else if(strR) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        temp.add(s);
    }

Or simple you can do
    if(strL && strR) {
        temp.add(s);
    } else (!strL && !strR) {
        temp.add(s);
    }

Hopefully it will work

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove from the `temp` list.

The only thing to do is to test the value that you get at each iteration from the list you passed in parameter:

- check if both conditions are true, in this case just add the original word.
- test if it contains a `l`, then multiply it by two
- otherwise do nothing (you didn't precise what to do for words that doesn't contain `l` and `r`):

---

```
if(strL && strR) {
    temp.add(s);
} else if(strL){
    temp.add(s);
    temp.add(s);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
liar
lisa
lisa
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer...**

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("rose"); // 0
        list.add("love"); // 1
        list.add("lyre"); // 2
        list = fix(list);

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fix(ArrayList<String> list) {
        // 
        ArrayList<String> teampList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String mainList = list.get(i);

            boolean checkL = mainList.contains("l");
            boolean checkR = mainList.contains("r");

            if (checkR) {
                teampList.remove(mainList);
            }
            if (checkL && checkR) {
                teampList.add(mainList);
            } else {
                if (!checkL && !checkR) {
                    teampList.add(mainList);
                }

                if (checkL) {
                    teampList.add(mainList);
                    teampList.add(mainList);
                }
            }

        }//end for
        return teampList;
    }

}
```